# How to position a border at the top?

Tags: html, css

It should be simple, but I don't know how. What I want is that the `.current` class adds a border to the current list item within the navigation menu.

I've done this already (see example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jARqOr)
But I would like to have the border aligned to the top of the header, like in this imag (the red border):

[image]

What should I do to get this result?

Looking forward to your response.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 2 borders? In you image, I see a thick black border and a thin red border. Or you mean this?: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrYzNm

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Only the red border. Black is Photoshop..

Comment: A **minimal** demo is required...you have way too much CSS in your Codepen.

Comment: Use my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the **best** solution, but this worked:

```
ul li a.current {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: -55px;
}
```

Setting margin-top to -55px (the negative value of the header's padding) takes it to the top, and then adding a padding-top of 50px (55px - 5px for the border) brings the text down to be even with the other anchor elements.

One issue with this solution is that all the space above the .current anchor is part of the clickable area.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and yes, that's which is unfortunate indeed. Is there a solution for?

Comment: There's likely a solution out there, but not one that I'm aware of right now. Hopefully someone else can provide some input.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your comment

## black is Photoshop

anyways this code just use CSS.

[see output you want just using CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/UserIsMonica/ygzhfz95/1/)

-- CSS --

```
  ul li a.current {
             border-top: 4px solid #000;
            /*box-shadow:  0px -5px 0px black;*/
             padding :0px 5px 5px 5px;
             color: red!important;
   }

   ul li a.current span {
            padding:5px 0px ;
            border-top: 2px solid red;
            /*box-shadow: 0px -2px 0px red;*/
     
   }
```

--- same size double border then
use this CSS instead

```
 ul li a.current {
      box-shadow:  0px -5px 0px black,  /* add as many as you want */
      inset  0px 2px 0px red;
      padding:5px;
      color: red!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
ul .current a {
    padding-top: 42px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #005f37 0%,#005f37 100%); 
    background-size: 100% 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #006038;
}
```

It works for me